# What are the resistance values for a 1970s GM fuel level sender?

Tags: electrical, fuel-tank

I'm looking for a chart that will tell me the resistance values for each fuel level. There are a few such charts like that for resistance readings on coolant temperature senders. Does anyone know of one for the fuel level sender as well?

Comment: Can you specify which GM model(s) this applies to? I don't know those cars well, but it might help make the question more helpful/searchable.

Answer (score 2):

Fuel level senders, when operating normally, produce a resistance value that is directly proportional to the level of fuel in the tank. The value should change smoothly as the float on the arm goes up and down. You should see no sudden jumps in resistance.

If a sender is bad, it can show the gas level as full, empty, or sporadically jumpy. Is this the problem that you are trying to diagnose?

Comment: I think that the OP is trying to find the values for full and empty perhaps.